# How to prevent .detach from trying to .detach elements that don't exist in the DOM

Tags: jquery, user-interface, widget, detach

*Context* – jQuery widget factory, rendering elements and storing them in private variables.

```
_renderInputHolder: function () {

    var self = this;

    this._inputHolder = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .on('focusout', function (e) {
        self._hideInputHolder.apply(self, [e]);
    });

},

_renderTextInput: function () {

    var self = this;

    this._textInput = $(document.createElement('input'))
        .keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            self._hideInputHolder();
        }
    });
},

_hideInputHolder: function () {

    this._inputHolder = this._inputHolder.detach();

},
```

*Problem* – two separate elements have independent events that try to detach the container element. When the enter keypress occurs on the text input, it detaches the inputContainer but this also causes a 'focusout' event to be triggered on the inputContainer, resulting in a

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

as it tries to detach it again.

What's the best way to ensure the inputContainer's removal without error OR check that .detach() can be called?

Comment: you can hold a state variable using `data()` to see whether the element is detached

Comment: like `if(!this._inputHolder.data('detached')){
    this._inputHolder = this._inputHolder.detach().data('detached', true);
}`

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks! This is the solution I think, I was going the same route but had forgotten about data(). I'm new to this process - how do I make your comment into the Answer/Solution?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hold a state variable using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to see whether the element is detached

```
if(!this._inputHolder.data('detached')){
    this._inputHolder = this._inputHolder.data('detached', true).detach();
}
```

Comment: I reordered .detach().data() to .data().detach() as it turns out setting data after detachment didn't work, however setting the data before detaching does. Will accept as answer, if the edit is agreeable.

Comment: another way to kill something like it... +1

Answer (score 0):

you can check if there's an element...

```
 _hideInputHolder: function() {
    if ($(this._inputHolder,'body').length) {
         this._inputHolder = this._inputHolder.detach();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately as the element is stored in a variable, the length will always return 1 (before and after detach).

Comment: @Qro how about checking if the element can be found in the body... see edited code..

Comment: Unfortunately $(this._inputHolder,'body').length still returns 1 after detach, though I think this would work in other cases.